# Editable multiple polygon using dragListener in Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-v2

I would like to implement multiple polygons with an editable using a drag listener. I am able to draw the multiple polygons but I don't know how to make editable.

I am able to move marker for current polygon but when I try to move previous polygon’s marker app is crash. I tried with saving polygon list but I can not able to drag the marker.

please see my code HERE.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (readyToGo()) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
            // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
            SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

            if (savedInstanceState == null) {
                mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
            }

            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        CameraUpdate center =
                CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(40.76793169992044,
                        -73.98180484771729));
        CameraUpdate zoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15);
        mMap.moveCamera(center);
        mMap.animateCamera(zoom);
        mMap.setIndoorEnabled(false);

        mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {

                Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).draggable(true));
                marker.setTag(latLng);
                markerList.add(marker);
                points.add(latLng);
                drawPolygon(points);
            }
        });


        mMap.setOnMarkerDragListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onMarkerDrag(Marker marker) {
                updateMarkerLocation(marker, false);
            }

            @Override
            public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {
                updateMarkerLocation(marker, true);

            }
        });

    }

    public void closePolygon(View view) {

    }

    public void newPolygon(View view) {

//
        points.clear();
        markerList.clear();
        polygon = null;
//        mMap.clear();
    }

    private void updateMarkerLocation(Marker marker, boolean calculate) {
        LatLng latLng = (LatLng) marker.getTag();
        int position = points.indexOf(latLng);
        points.set(position, marker.getPosition());
        marker.setTag(marker.getPosition());
        drawPolygon(points);

    }

    private void drawPolygon(List<LatLng> latLngList) {
        if (polygon != null) {
            polygon.remove();
        }
        polygonOptions = new PolygonOptions();
        polygonOptions.addAll(latLngList);
        polygon = mMap.addPolygon(polygonOptions);

    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "multiple polygons" - the code posted maintains one polygon by removing/re-adding with additional point.

Comment: When you press New polygon it is drawing new one. @Andy Please check this link for full code https://github.com/arpit999/Polygon

Comment: OK - that must be a button or something - I have your code running as posted and works great but I didn't have that new polygon capability.

Comment: Yes there is button for the New polygon please check out the full code from the github @Andy

Comment: Can i get android example code in which polygon is drawn and markers are movable

Comment: @Tara https://github.com/arpit999/Polygon
Enjoy :)

Comment: @Arpit Patel, I have downloaded above said project but markers are not dragging.. I want an exmaple where in markers are draggable and when it drags it should reshape a polygon.

Comment: @Tara Are you holding the marker and dragging it?

Comment: yes. I want the functionality to hold and drag.

Comment: Try to hold marker and drag it. It is working on the project I checked it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically this approach keeps the markers and points as collections associated with each polygon.  It simplifies things by assuming after 5 markers a new polygon is created (equivalent to an add polygon).

**UPDATED**: To use the "new polygon" button as defined in the layout in github.  Button listener just sets a flag and instead of using a size=5 check replace the check with the flag.

A map from any marker to its corresponding list is maintained for use in the `updateMarkerLocation` method.

All of this is predicated on the fact that any marker has a unique id provided by the map API `getId()` which in practice is a string like "m7".

I've listed the parts updated:

```
// Map a marker id to its corresponding list (represented by the root marker id)
HashMap<String,String> markerToList = new HashMap<>();

// A list of markers for each polygon (designated by the marker root).
HashMap<String,List<Marker>> polygonMarkers = new HashMap<>();

// A list of polygon points for each polygon (designed by the marker root).
HashMap<String,List<LatLng>> polygonPoints = new HashMap<>();

// List of polygons (designated by marker root).
HashMap<String,Polygon> polygons = new HashMap<>();

// The active polygon (designated by marker root) - polygon added to.
String markerListKey;

// Flag used to record when the 'New Polygon' button is pressed.  Next map
// click starts a new polygon.
boolean newPolygon = false;

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    CameraUpdate center =
            CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(40.76793169992044,
                    -73.98180484771729));
    CameraUpdate zoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15);
    mMap.moveCamera(center);
    mMap.animateCamera(zoom);
    mMap.setIndoorEnabled(false);

    Button b = findViewById(R.id.bt_new_polygon);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            newPolygon = true;
        }
    });

    mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {

            Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).draggable(true));
            marker.setTag(latLng);

            // Special case for very first marker.
            if (polygonMarkers.size() == 0) {
                polygonMarkers.put(marker.getId(),new ArrayList<Marker>());
                // only 0 or 1 polygons so just add it to new one or existing one.
                markerList = new ArrayList<>();
                points = new ArrayList<>();
                polygonMarkers.put(marker.getId(),markerList);
                polygonPoints.put(marker.getId(),points);
                markerListKey = marker.getId();
            }

            if (newPolygon) {
                newPolygon = false;
                markerList = new ArrayList<>();
                points = new ArrayList<>();
                polygonMarkers.put(marker.getId(),markerList);
                polygonPoints.put(marker.getId(),points);
                markerListKey = marker.getId();
            }

            markerList.add(marker);
            points.add(latLng);
            markerToList.put(marker.getId(),markerListKey);

            drawPolygon(markerListKey, points);
        }
    });


private void updateMarkerLocation(Marker marker, boolean calculate) {

    // Use the marker to figure out which polygon list to use...
    List<LatLng> pts = polygonPoints.get(markerToList.get(marker.getId()));
    
    // This is much the same except use the retrieved point list.
    LatLng latLng = (LatLng) marker.getTag();
    int position = pts.indexOf(latLng);
    pts.set(position, marker.getPosition());
    marker.setTag(marker.getPosition());
    drawPolygon(markerToList.get(marker.getId()),pts);

}

private void drawPolygon(String mKey, List<LatLng> latLngList) {

    // Use the existing polygon (if any) for the root marker.
    Polygon polygon = polygons.get(mKey);
    if (polygon != null) {
        polygon.remove();
    }
    polygonOptions = new PolygonOptions();
    polygonOptions.addAll(latLngList);
    polygon = mMap.addPolygon(polygonOptions);
    
    // And update the list for the root marker.
    polygons.put(mKey,polygon);
}
```

### Initial

Initial collection of 3 polygons added by clicking on map...

[image]

### Modified

Then an image showing a point in each polygon stretched...

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer I will try it and let you know

Comment: This is what I am looking for but there is one problem it's limited to the 5 markers I want the new polygon after a click on the button.

Comment: Took a look at layout in github project and added a button listener to the `bt_new_polygon` which simply sets a flag.  On the next map click a new polygon is started - instead of using the polygon size.  Not exactly sure the user experience expected but hopefully gives you something to work with.  Also not sure how the close button is supposed to work.